# Why does HorizontalPager not remember PagerState when it is stored in a ViewModel or a global?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, horizontal-pager

Whenever I try to move the pager state from the composable to my viewmodels the pager state stops *remembering* and the currently selected page is reset to zero on screen rotation changes. Here, I'm pasting a full working example where there are two lines commented:

- Option 1 uses a `PagerState` object stored in a viewmodel, which survives screen rotation and thus should keep the current page.
- Option 2 uses a `rememberPagerState()` inside the composable `Wrapper`.

So when I run the example using option 1 (viewmodel), reach the last page and rotate the screen, or enter window mode, change dark mode, or anything that generates a configuration change, the page is lost and I return to page 0. However, when I use the option 2 (rememberPagerState) the page is kept. Ironically, the `print()` that is placed before the `HorizontalPager` shows that when running the viewmodel option the object address is the same, yet in option 2 it changes every time.

What is going on? Why does `HorizontalPager` reset the page when I'm passing `PagerState` from the `ViewModel` or a global?

```kotlin
class TestViewModel: ViewModel() {

    @OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
    val pagerState = PagerState()

    init {
        println("ddd Initializing TestViewModel!")
    }
}

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val vm: TestViewModel by viewModels()

    @OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            PagerStateTheme {
                Wrapper(vm.pagerState)
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun Wrapper(pagerState: PagerState) {

    val otherState = rememberPagerState()
    //Test(pagerState = pagerState) // option 1
    //Test(pagerState = otherState) // option 2
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun Test(pagerState: PagerState) {

    println("ddd pager state object is $pagerState")
    HorizontalPager(
        pageCount = 4,
        state = pagerState,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        pageSpacing = 8.dp,
        pageSize = PageSize.Fixed(300.dp),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(
            start = 20.dp,
            end = 20.dp,
            top = 60.dp
        ),
    ) { pageIndex ->
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            Text("Hello page $pageIndex")
        }
    }
}
```

This example was built from the current Android Studio IDE template, after adding the following gradle dependencies:

```kotlin
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.05.01')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1"
```

Comment: Compose already remembers the state for you. You're doing something wrong.